# Incompatible pointer type when making structure of function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I'm trying to make a array of structures which contain a string and a function pointer, however when I compile I get a warning that I've initialized from an incompatible pointer type.

I have no idea why (sorry if I sound ignorant, I'm fairly new to C programming).

```
 typedef struct
{
    char Player1[2], Player[2], **gameGrid;
    int height,width;
    int moveNum, player1Num, player2Num;
    bool player1Win, player2Win;
}Game;

typedef int (*pointer_func)(Game *);

typedef struct
{
   char *funcName;
   pointer_func *f;
}userFunc;

int save(Game *struc);
int load(Game *struc);
int move(Game *struc);
int quit(Game *struc);
void free_grid(Game *struc);


int main(){
//initialised variables 

userFunc Name_arr[] = {
    {"save",save},
    {"load",load},
    {"quit",quit},
    {"move",move}
};
```

The four functions being referenced are as follows:

```
int save(Game *struc)
{
char *str, *inputString, *writeString;
FILE *fp;
int nextPlayer;
int maxRead = 20;
bool DIRresponse;

while(true)
{
    printf("Please provide a file name (20 characters max): ");
    inputString = input_String(inputString, maxRead, stdin);

    if((DIRresponse = check_Directory(inputString)) == true){
        printf("That name already exists, choose another\n");
        continue;
    }
    else
        break;  
}

if(struc->moveNum % 2 == 0)
    nextPlayer = struc->player1Num;
else
    nextPlayer = struc->player2Num;

sprintf(str,"%s.txt",inputString);
fp = fopen(str,"w");

sprintf(writeString, "%d %d %d %d %d",  nextPlayer, struc->height,
            struc->width, struc->moveNum, struc->moveNum);
fprintf(fp,writeString);

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}

int move(Game *struc)
{
 return 1;
}

int load(Game *struc)
{
 return 1;
}

int quit(Game *struc)
{
 free_grid(struc);
 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Please make your [mcve] more minimal.

Comment: Please post the exact text of the compiler warning, and if needed, indicate where the line is in your code.

Comment: try to explicity cast and set values : ```userFunc Name_arr[] = {
    (userFunc){ .funcName = "save", .f = save} /* other array items */ };```

Comment: pointer_func is already a pointer, you have pointer to pointer to function initialized with pointer to functions.

Comment: BTW, you don't allocate any space for `str` or `write_string`, and the `sprintf` can be merged with the `fprintf`.

Comment: Dunke comrades, I appreciate the feedback, I will use your input to better my practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mismatch in levels of pointers:

```
typedef int (*pointer_func)(Game *); << Pointer type

typedef struct
{
  char *funcName;
  pointer_func *f;              << Pointer to a pointer type.... OOPS
}userFunc;
```

Make `*f` -> `f` and it should work.

Comment: Ahhh, I always feel so stupid after being shown what I've overlooked, regardless thank you for the swift and elegant response.

Comment: Good. Then you will remember it and don't do it again. ;)